# What is wrong with my ajax code?

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to read a xml file but the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) code I have keeps going to error instead of success. What could be causing this?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/gallery.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            alert("Asd");

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ad");
        }
    });
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gallery>
    <image src="images/field.jpg"/>
</gallery>
```

Comment: This could be a stupid question, but are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: I know what's wrong with your question: The title and the fact that you don't tell us what's 'not working' or what kind of error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX requests can't access the local file system, so requests like this will fail.

You will need to have the page up on a Web Server.

You can use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or similar for a basic Web Server to test on you local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `error` handler to

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);}
```

This should allow you to see more information about the error.

Comment: I've copied your code into my code but when it goes to display, the actual error it displays is blank "error: (blank)"

Comment: You are running this on a server right? not off the local filesystem... correct?

Comment: It's in a folder on my desktop, so local. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes - you can't run AJAX locally (or at least you should expect errors/issues doing so)

Comment: Try checking `jqXHR.statusCode` to see if it has completed correctly. It should be `200`

Answer (score 0):

What is the location of the page your Ajax function on, and what is the absolute path to the XML file you are trying to load?

You are referencing your XML using a relative path (xml/gallery.xml), so if the XML is not in a subdirectory xml RELATIVE to the page you are using the Ajax function on, this will fail.  That may be what's causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the website using a LAMP Stack (or something like XAMPP?). If you are trying to run the above code directly from an html file on your desktop it's not going to work.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I'd strongly reccomend using something like XAMPP or even better run a copy of linux (either on a computer or as a VM) - that matches the environment you are planning to deploy in.